# Trying to split a string in Java, containing newlines, !, spaces, ?, commas, etc

Tags: java, regex, split

I know there are many threads about this, but I try the regular expression `//W+` and it doesn't work like I expect it to.

I'm taking a Java course, and I have a long string of text, that's actually an excerpt from a Shakespeare play.  So, it has many punctuation signs, spaces, new line characters, etc.
The explanation for the exercise tells me to use `message.split("//W+")` to split it and receive an array, with each field containing one of the words.

But it's not working for me.  The exercise seems to work with another regex, if I use `message.split(" ")` for example.  I get fields with the words that are separated by spaces, but many words are joined by `\n` or have `!` at the end.

This is my code, with a short text:

```
public void testSplit(){
    String message = ("This is the message to split!");
    String[] splitMsg= message.split("//W+");
    for (int k=0; k<splitMsg.length;k++){
        System.out.println(splitMsg[k]);
    }
 }
```

The output is the string, `This is the message to split!`

Thanks!

Comment: OK, I feel pretty dumb now... I knew it was probably something simple I wasn't doing right.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the escaping is with `\\` not with `//`.

Update: Try to test your sample with this tool [Regexr](http://regexr.com/). You'll see that works with \w+, but how this expression just checks for words, the exclamation char will be not included.

Comment: OK, I feel pretty dumb now... I knew it was probably something simple I wasn't doing right.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem, we are here for this. No one knows everything and this includes me. Luck!!!

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the wrong regex argument into the split function. \W+ should be //W+

```
public void testSplit(){
    String message = ("This is the message to split!");
    String[] splitMsg= message.split("//W+");
    for (int k=0; k<splitMsg.length;k++){
        System.out.println(splitMsg[k]);
    }
 }
```

Comment: OK, I feel pretty dumb now... I knew it was probably something simple I wasn't doing right.  Thanks!